# Changed nothing, suddenly recieving Ionic TypeError co.event is undefined

Tags: javascript, android, node.js, ionic-framework, ionic2

I don't have much information, because it's the weirdest problem I have ever had.

I'm writing an app in Ionic 2.  Last night I went to bed with everything being fine. I get up this morning to continue work and even though the Welcome Page loads, when you scroll through to the Home Page I get an error that co.event is undefined.

Here's a screenshot of the spectacularly unhelpful error message (why can't I copy paste error messages from this error screen in Ionic? So stupid).  Searching "co.event" in my codebase returns 0 results.

[image: Error Message]

I had not changed a single line of code anywhere. I don't even understand how this is possible, let alone what to do to fix it.

I switched from the branch I was working on to Master branch to see if that was still fine. No, that has a completely different error despite zero changes being made to that either.

[image]

I can solve the error on master branch by going into `src/app/app.component.ts` and commenting out `this.initializeApp();` which makes everything work but seems like a really bad idea because that sounds like a pretty crucial line to include.

```
constructor(public platform: Platform, public statusBar: StatusBar, public splashScreen: SplashScreen) {
  // this.initializeApp();

  // used for an example of ngFor and navigation
  this.pages = [
    { title: 'Welcome', component: WelcomePage },
    { title: 'Home', component: HomePage },
    { title: 'List', component: ListPage }
  ];

}
```

Any help much appreciated.

Edit updates:

Here's my `initializeApp`

```
initializeApp() {
  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
    // Okay, so the platform is ready and our plugins are available.
    // Here you can do any higher level native things you might need.
    this.statusBar.styleDefault();
    this.splashScreen.hide();

    // Enable to debug issues.
    // window["plugins"].OneSignal.setLogLevel({logLevel: 4, visualLevel: 4});
    var notificationOpenedCallback = function(jsonData) {
      console.log('notificationOpenedCallback: ' + JSON.stringify(jsonData));
    };

    // window["plugins"].OneSignal
    // .startInit("yyyyyyyyy", "yyyyyyyyy")
    // .handleNotificationOpened(notificationOpenedCallback)
    // .endInit();
  });
}
```

And here's the THIRD different error (despite having literally changed nothing????) that appears when running the dev branch on my Android phone instead of in `ionic serve`.  Master branch works fine on Android phone.

[image: Another error]

Edit 2: Home page code

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <button ion-button menuToggle>
      <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    <ion-title>Home</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>
  <h1 class="header">Nuevo Niño</h1>
  <hr />

  <div ng-app ng-init="qty=1;cost=2">
    <button ion-button (click)="setData()">SetData</button>
    <button ion-button (click)="getData()">GetData</button>

    <br />
    <b>Name:</b> {{name}}



    <hr />

    <b>Invoice:</b>
    <div>
      Quantity: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="HomePage.qty">
    </div>
    <div>
      Costs: <input type="number" min="0" ng-model="cost">
    </div>
    <div>
      <b>Total:</b> {{qty * cost | currency}}
    </div>
  </div>


  <p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed quis ipsum id libero auctor viverra eget vitae ipsum. Aenean ultrices diam odio, ac vulputate felis ultrices vel. Donec a mauris tristique, feugiat nunc nec, lacinia augue.
  </p>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-item>
      <ion-label>Expected Birth Date</ion-label>
      <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY" [(ngModel)]="event.month"></ion-datetime>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <p><b>Baby arrives {{ days_until_birth }}!</b></p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <ion-list>
    <ion-list-header>
      Recent Notifications
    </ion-list-header>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="assets/img/avatar-ben.png">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Doctor Smith</h2>
      <h3>24th January</h3>
      <p>3 month check-up</p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="assets/img/avatar-han.png">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Han</h2>
      <h3>Look, kid...</h3>
      <p>I've got enough on my plate as it is, and I...</p>
    </ion-item>

    <ion-item>
      <ion-avatar item-start>
        <img src="assets/img/avatar-leia.png">
      </ion-avatar>
      <h2>Leia</h2>
      <h3>I can handle myself</h3>
      <p>You will remove these restraints and leave...</p>
    </ion-item>
  </ion-list>

  <!-- <button ion-button secondary menuToggle>Toggle Menu</button> -->
</ion-content>
```

and the .ts file

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController } from 'ionic-angular';
import moment from 'moment';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.html'
})

export class HomePage {

  name: string = 'John';

  // public days_until_birth = moment('20171119', 'YYYYMMDD').fromNow();
  // let data = moment()
  // let data = moment().format('YYYYMMDD');
  // let time = moment().format('HHmmss');
  // console.log('today is: ', data + ' and time: ', time);

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public storage: Storage) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.storage.set('name', 'James');
  }

  setData(){
    this.storage.set('name', 'Brett');
  }

  getData(){
    this.storage.get('name').then((data) => {
      console.log(data);
    });
  }


}
```

Comment: Is this in a device/emulator or ionic serve? and what does initializeApp() contain?

Comment: @suraj On ionic serve. On Android device, master branch is fine and the dev branch has a THIRD different error. See OP edits.

Comment: The case is not what you've changed, using plugins in browser surely will break your application since there's no way of accessing plugins. But there's something worng in your home page, both first and third error shows something is wrong on homepage, can you show your HomePage code? Maybe there's something there whose depends on plugins and since they can't be used on web, it throws errors.

Comment: @GabrielBarreto but it worked totally fine last night and I haven't changed anything.  I've added in the Home Page code if that helps.

Comment: I redownloaded from the Github repo into a fresh folder, and now after removing moment.js it appears the master branch doesn't work but the dev branch does.  This is such a mess.  Anyway if the dev branch keeps working then I'll mark this as closed, god knows why it wasn't (and still isn't on master branch) working.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so by your code we can get the following:

- For the second error it's probably because you're trying to access plugins via your `window` object and plugins doesn't exist in it since there's no cordova available.
- I highly sugest you using [ionic-native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/) since they made all work of wrapping plugins so we can have a better and simpler use of them.
- if it's possible always call your plugins after checking if the platform if cordova, iOS or Android so it doesn't break your application when not testing on emulators (in production/test you can take out this checkings, but for production it's good to have), so try to use your code inside of a `if(this.platform.is('cordova')){}`.
- The `co.event` error in your home is simply because you don't have an `event` variable declared in your HomePage, thus it can't recognize the `event` and `event.month`. So i sugest check all your home page bindings and .ts variables and functions.

Hope this helps.